# Class 'Mockery' not found

Tags: unit-testing, laravel, laravel-4, phpunit, mockery

I use laravel (4.1) framework and i read "Laravel-testing-decoded", it's a ebook by Jeffrey Wey.

I want to test my modal User and my method `setPasswordAttribute($password)`

My unit-testing :

```
<?php

class UserTest extends TestCase {

    public function testHashesPasswordWhenSet(){

        Hash::shouldReceive('make')->once()->andReturn('hashed');

        $user = new User;
        $user->password = 'food';

        $this->assertEquals('hashed', $user->password);
    }
}
```

But when i launch CLI : `phpunit` it return me a error : `Fatal error: Class 'Mockery' not found`

In complete error :

```
    Fatal error: Class 'Mockery' not found in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php on line 84

    Call Stack:
        0.0021     236384   1. {main}() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:0
        0.0294    1425104   2. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command::main() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/composer/bin/phpunit:63
        0.0294    1425336   3. PHPUnit_TextUI_Command->run() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:129
        0.0692    3626416   4. PHPUnit_TextUI_TestRunner->doRun() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/Command.php:176
        0.0741    3944720   5. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/TextUI/TestRunner.php:349
        0.0741    3946368   6. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->run() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:705
        0.0742    3946968   7. PHPUnit_Framework_TestSuite->runTest() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:745
        0.0742    3947000   8. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->run() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestSuite.php:775
        0.0743    3948232   9. PHPUnit_Framework_TestResult->run() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:783
        0.0754    4005504  10. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runBare() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestResult.php:648
        0.2926   15417592  11. PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase->runTest() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:838
        0.2926   15418872  12. ReflectionMethod->invokeArgs() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983
        0.2926   15418904  13. UserTest->testHashesPasswordWhenSet() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/phpunit/phpunit/PHPUnit/Framework/TestCase.php:983
        0.2928   15426728  14. Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::shouldReceive() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/app/tests/models/UserTest.php:7
        0.2928   15426944  15. Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::createFreshMockInstance() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:50
        0.2928   15427040  16. Illuminate\Support\Facades\Facade::createMockByName() /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/ptf/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Facades/Facade.php:64
```

I don't understand, why i have this error.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Do you have Mockery installed?
If not, update your **composer.json**:

```
"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev"
}
```

Then run:

```
 composer update
```

Comment: Thanks for help, it's oki. but normally Laravel require also mockery : https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/master/composer.json#L71

Comment: fyi it has been renamed to "dev-main"