# No Mockery found in test class

Tags: java, junit, mocking

I'm writing a new unit test and am getting a `java.lang.Exception` thrown with the error "no Mockery found in test class". This is happening as an `initializationError` which makes sense as I'm setting up the mocks in an `@Before` method.

Does anyone know what causes this error and what needs to be done to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. I had somehow copied in an:

```
@RunWith(JMockCategoryRunner.class)
```

annotation from another file and removing that got rid of the problem.

Answer (score 1):

In newer situations you might want to look into the property junit.jupiter.extensions.autodetection.enabled. JMock seems to have a challenge with respect to this. Read: https://github.com/jmock-developers/jmock-library/issues/155 No official fix available yet. But it helped me to fix things in my situation: I had to exclude the artifact quarkus-junit5-properties in my Quarkus project under dependency quarkus-junit5. This artifact caused the above setting to be set to true.

Answer (score -2):

Do you have Mockery installed?
If not, update your **composer.json**:

```
"require-dev": {
    "mockery/mockery": "dev-master@dev"
}
```

Then run:

```
composer update
```

answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20826539/class-mockery-not-found)

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I think I found the cause though. See my answer

Comment: This is a Java question, not PHP.